# Guzzle httpClient Drupal Core throwing cURL error 28 Operation timed out

Tags: 8, http-request

I have been loading the httpClient Core Service in a drupal 8 site. The service class works just fine when the request doesn't take too long from the API. It seems that if the request takes any longer than about 20-30 seconds the site throws a cURL response error 28 saying

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Operation timed out  after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection() (line 186 of ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php).
```

After a bit of poking around online I saw some reference to the fact that the "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS" error doesn't work with all versions of php and they suggest to replace the reference to "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS" to "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT" same for "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS".

In the above file with the error I found that in lines 374-380 which read the following

```
if (isset($options['timeout'])) {
  $conf[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS] = $options['timeout'] * 1000;
}
if (isset($options['connect_timeout'])) {
   $conf[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS] = $options['connect_timeout'] * 1000;
}
```

if it's changed to the following

```
if (isset($options['timeout'])) {
    $conf[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = $options['timeout'] * 1000;
}
if (isset($options['connect_timeout'])) {
   $conf[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = $options['connect_timeout'] * 1000;
}
```

removing the "_MS" then the site doesn't throw any errors.

Is this an error in the core code? Is this issue possibly related and can it be fixed with the patches attached to [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2248827) d.o issue? Also please see [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2248827#comment-11000551) comment on that issue with reference to what I mentioned above.

Any suggestions or direction on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't have a use of undefined constant error (as far as you reported), so your problem is probably different. CurlFactory is within Guzzle, so if there is a bug in there, it isn't Drupal. The thing to find out is what connect_timeout and timeout are set to in the calling code.

Comment: Unless you are not logging notices.

Comment: @cilefen Thanks for the response. I checked my logs for any php notices and I don't see any notices related to this issue. How would I go about finding out what the connect_timeout and timeout are set to in the calling code? I did try setting the connect_timeout manually in my local.settings.php file but that didn't seem to help..

Answer (score 3):

As @cilefen suggested in his comments my problem was related to the timeout value that was being set in the calling code rather then an error with an undefined constant. I had fixed the error in my particular situation by adjusting the timeout value in my custom code that was making the API call with the following (600 is an example).

```
$request = $client->post($url, [
  'timeout' => 600,
  'json' => [array(...)],
]);
```